# jQuery slider and images in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have some images: 1.png, 2.png, 3.png. 4.png. 5.png, arrow_back.png and arrow_forward.png.
They're in the assets/images folder. I'm making an image slider, where user can toggle back and forth with the back-forward arrows. My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="carousel.css">

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<!-- the carousel div, which holds the back and forward arrows on each side, and the 
changing images, in the middle -->
<div id = "carousel">
  <img id ="rotate_images" src="1.png"/>
  <!-- back arrow -->
  <div id = "back">
  <img src = "arrow_back.png">
</div>  
<!-- forward arrow -->
  <div id = "forward">
  <img src = "arrow_forward.png">
</div>

</div>

<script>

$('#back').on({
    'click': function () {
        var origsrc = $(rotate_images).attr('src');
        var src = '';
        if (origsrc == '5.png') src = '4.png';
        if (origsrc == '4.png') src = '3.png';
        if (origsrc == '3.png') src = '2.png';
        if (origsrc == '2.png') src = '1.png';
        if (origsrc == '1.png') src = '1.png';
        $(rotate_images).attr('src', src);
    }
});

$('#forward').on({
    'click': function () {
        var origsrc = $(rotate_images).attr('src');
        var src = '';
        if (origsrc == '1.png') src = '2.png';
        if (origsrc == '2.png') src = '3.png';
        if (origsrc == '3.png') src = '4.png';
        if (origsrc == '4.png') src = '5.png';
        if (origsrc == '5.png') src = '5.png';
        $(rotate_images).attr('src', src);
    }
});
</script>
```

However, my images are not appearing, when I start my App on localhost - just empty boxes. Is it really necessary to use standard Rails code all the time like:

```
<%= image_tag "arrow_back.png" %>
```

How can I modify my jQuery code so it will work this way? As you can see it uses the 'src' attribute but I don't know how to work this with image_tag. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `They're in the assets/images folder.` ... then ... `<img id ="rotate_images" src="1.png"/>` Why are you not doing `assets/images/1.png`? Also, use a `console`, most browsers have one built in these days, if not, look for `Web inspector` for your flavor of browser...then, check the console, if it can't find the image because of a location issue, you will see the error there...makes debugging much easier.

Comment: Thanks, but when I change my <image src> code to <image src = "assets/images/image.src" the images still are not appearing.

Comment: Then check your console, as I suggested earlier. It'll tell you why it's not working. I don't have a magic device that allows me to see your file structure, so I have no idea where you're calling this from.

Comment: I'm using Chrome. Console gives me the error, 'GET http://localhost:3000/assets/images/1.png 404 (Not Found). And 1.png is located in the assets/images folder.

Comment: And the file you're calling these images from can be navigated to by going to `localhost:3000` in the browser, yes?

Comment: Got the images showing. In fact, you don't include 'images' in the asset pipeline. It should  be just "assets/1.png". Thanks for your help.